# Problem with "not" in full text search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, full-text-search

I don't understand why I'm getting these results with my full-text search query in SQL Server 2014.

The following query returns results with "Supervisor" in the `Title` field and "Tokyo" in the `HTML_Description` field.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([post], (Title, HTML_Description), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

If I remove the `HTML_Description` field in the `CONTAINSTABLE` like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post 
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(post, (Title), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

The result is the same.

If I use only the `HTML_Description` field in the `CONTAINSTABLE` like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post 
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(post, (HTML_Description), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

There aren't any results.

How can I apply the `NOT` operator to all fields?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with full text searches but I think [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2237443/5190842) gives us the answer which is also supported by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801285/5190842).  The solution was to create a computed column containing what is essentially a concatenation of all the columns you want to apply your search terms to and do your full text search on that column.

Alternatively you can use the `AND`, `OR`, `NOT` logic in separate expressions like the OP in the StackOverflow answer I linked to.

That being said someone here might have a better solution.